# How to relate alpha and beta arguments of beta distribution between the numpy.random.beta(alpha, beta) and scipy.stats.beta(alpha, beta, loc, scale)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm using numpy distributions for generating random numbers for montecarlo simulations and Fitter library for fitting distributions to results. The problem is that the fitted parameters are returned accordingly to scipy library as 4 parameters (a, b, loc, scale) and I need to find the equivalent parameters for numpy (a,b).

If I fit a scipy.stats.beta(a,b,loc=0, scale=1)(blue line) it is equal to a numpy.random.beta(a,b)(bars)
[image]

I've tried to fit them with scify.stats.beta.fit(x, floc=0, fscale=1) and I get the following error:

scipy.stats._continuous_distns.FitDataError: Invalid values in `data`. Maximum likelihood estimation with 'beta' requires that 0 < (x - loc)/scale < 1 for each x in `data`.

If I don't set floc to 0 and fscale to 1 it returns results like:
[147.1,147.06,-23.56,137.13] which are a,b, loc, scale.

How can I transform them to a a,b,loc=0, scale=1?

My problem is that I'm creating a software in which users create input variables following probability distributions, performs Monte Carlo simulations and get the results of the output variables. I’m performing the fitting to distributions to those variables and need to return the parameters of the fitting to the user in the same format the initially enter them. If user uses alpha and beta parameters to create variables following beta distributions, I cannot return them 4 parameters to simulate a Beta distribution.
I’ve been able to accomplish it with the other distributions I need, but I’m stack with Beta

Comment: To improve this and future questions please include a small subset of your data as a copyable piece of code that can be used for testing, as well as your expected output and the code you've tried.  See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the parameters `a`, `b`, `loc` and `scale` for the beta distribution, and you want to use NumPy to generate `n` random samples from the distribution, you can write

```
sample = loc + scale*np.random.beta(a, b, size=n)  # Legacy random API
```

or, using the newer (and recommended) API

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
sample = loc + scale*rng.beta(a, b, size=n)
```

You could also use the `rvs()` method of `scipy.stats.beta`:

```
sample = scipy.stats.beta.rvs(a, b, loc=loc, scale=scale, size=n)
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! However my problem still remains. Despite I can generate random numbers as you suggest, my problem is that I want to return the user the parameters the same way he/she uses. If user defines Beta distributions with 2 parameters I cannot return a fit with 4 parameters. I will edit my answer to further clarify this issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having a conceptual problem. To force loc and scale to be 0 and 1 as in numpy you can do:

betafun = scipy.stats.beta.fit(values, floc=0, fscale=1)

The problem there, is that a series of numbers cannot be adjusted in this way if there are values greater than 1 or less than 0, because I am precisely setting those limits with loc and scale values and the code is going to return an error.
If I need to adjust a series of numbers that are not in the range 0 to 1, the values of loc and scale cannot to be 0 and 1.